# AJAX- response data not saved to global scope?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope

I am having the issue of my below shown lines not storing the variable into the global scope:

```
var somedata;

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: verification_url,
    success: function(data){
        somedata = data;
    }
});

alert(somedata); // Undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to wrap this into a separate function or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `alert()` code runs before the response from `$.ajax` is received.

That's why it's `undefined`.

```
var somedata;

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: verification_url,
    success: function(data){
        somedata = data;

        alert( somedata );   // 2. this will occur after the response is received
    }
});

alert(somedata); // 1. this will occur first
```

Here you can see that the alerts happen out of order. By default an AJAX request does not prevent subsequent code from running.

That's the entire purpose of having a *callback* method. It is a method that gets called at the appropriate time, instead of relying on synchronous execution.

Comment: So what would be an appropriate alternative design then?

Comment: @industrial: Either use `somedata` in the callback, or make sure your design doesn't require information stored in `somedata` until after a successful ajax request.

Comment: add the alert to the success callback function.  or define a function before making the request and have it called within the success function.  either way what you want to have done needs to occur within the success function.  (if you want it to run async)

Comment: @Industrial: Any code that relies on the successful response needs to be located in your `success:` callback, or in a function that is invoked from the `success:` callback.

Answer (score 5):

AJAX is asynchronous. That's what the `A` stands for in the acronym. You can access the results only in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: verification_url,
    success: function(data){
        // HERE AND ONLY HERE YOU HAVE THE RESULTS
        // So it is here that you should manipulate them
        alert(data);
    }
});

// this line is executed MUCH BEFORE the success callback 
// and the server hasn't yet sent any response.
```

So any code that needs to manipulate the results must be place inside the success callback or in a function which is invoked from the success callback. You should not be relying on global state for this pattern.

Comment: Not entirely true, it can only be access _after_ the callback has been executed. (assuming `somedata` is assigned the returned result(s))

Comment: @Brad Christie, while this is true, it has no practical application as you don't know when the AJAX request completes. The only place you know is the success callback. Thus, as I said in my answer, that's the only place where you can know for sure that results are available. Any other place would be gambling.

Comment: Gambling, true. However, it is possible to retrieve the value of `somedata` after a successful callback. Though it may be gambling, I was just trying to make mention that's it's not _only_ accessible in the callback, just _impractical_.

Comment: @Brad Christie, can you provide an example where you would access the results of an asynchronous AJAX callback other than the success callback itself or a function invoked directly from within the success callback?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - narrow-minded and presumptive? Unless, of course, you DO know the requirements, limitations, design principles and developer preferences of every application ever written? What he wrote is factually correct :)

Comment: @Darin: I concede; you're clearly correct in all points and assertions.