# Javascript variable not being updated - possibly out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX- response data not saved to global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684014/ajax-response-data-not-saved-to-global-scope)

I basically have a loop that contacts a script on my site using AJAX and then updates a string with the response from that script. Here's the code:

```
    // Image code array
    var result_url = 'http://localhost/view/';

    for(i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        // Add URL to queue
        $('#url_queue').append('<div class="uploadifyQueueItem"><div class="cancel"><img src="/assets/img/cancel.png" /></div><span class="fileName">' + image_name_from_url(urls[i]) + '</span><div class="uploadifyProgress"><div class="uploadifyProgressBar"></div></div></div>');

        // Make a request to the upload script
        $.post('/upload', { url: urls[i], username: username }, function(response) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if(response.error) {
                alert(response.error);
                return;
            }
            if(response.img_code) {
                result_url += response.img_code + '&';
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(result_url);
```

The Firebug console just shows `http://localhost/view/` when the string is logged. It's like the `img_code` response from my upload script isn't being appended to the string at all. I have tried logging the value of `result_url` within the `$.post()` method and that works fine, but the value is not being saved properly because it doesn't show later in my code. Is this a scope problem? Will I have to define `result_url` as a global variable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if your script shown is at top-level scope, then `result_url` already is a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `console.log(result_url);` before the AJAX requests complete.

---

AJAX requests are (by default) run asynchronously. What that means is that your script continues to run while the request is still being made to the server.

Your callback function (provided to `$.post` as the 3rd parameter) is the one that get's executed *after* your AJAX request has completed.

---

Also note, that your AJAX request callback functions are called when the request is done. Your requests might not finish in the same order that they started. You could prevent all this by setting `async:false`, but that'll halt all of your javascript execution.

---

Another option would be to collect the `jqXHR` objects being returned by `$.post`, and then call `$.when().done()`, so that your `console.log(result_url)` happens only when all the AJAX requests are resolved:

```
// Image code array
var result_url = 'http://localhost/view/',
    jqHXRs = [];

for(i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // Add URL to queue
    $('#url_queue').append('<div class="uploadifyQueueItem"><div class="cancel"><img src="/assets/img/cancel.png" /></div><span class="fileName">' + image_name_from_url(urls[i]) + '</span><div class="uploadifyProgress"><div class="uploadifyProgressBar"></div></div></div>');

    // Make a request to the upload script
    jqHXRs.push($.post('/upload', { url: urls[i], username: username }, function(response) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
            return;
        }
        if(response.img_code) {
            result_url += response.img_code + '&';
        }
    }));
}

$.when.apply(this, jqHXRs).done(function(){
    console.log(result_url);
});
```

Comment: Arh yes, ofcourse. Thanks. Is there any way to prevent my code from continuing until the AJAX request has completed? I saw I could set a synchronous request but it said on the jQuery site that it can lock up a browser.

Comment: You should use the deffered objects returned by `$.post`, then you can use '$.when().done()': http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: @John: I updated the answer with a method to use deffered objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're doing the `console.log` immediately after firing the Ajax. Since Ajax is asynchronous, the success function will not necessarily be called before the code which follows your ajax code.

jQuery's Ajax tools provide a way of calling ajax synchronously by including the `async:false` option. Try replacing your ajax call with:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'/upload', 
    data:{ url: rls[i], username:username }, 
    success:function(response) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
            return;
        }
        if(response.img_code) {
            result_url += response.img_code + '&';
        }
    },
    method:"post",

    async:false

 });
```

That way, code which follows you Ajax call would only be executed after the ajax completes.

Remember, though that this will lock up your page for the duration of the Ajax. Maybe it would be easier to just put the `console.log(result_url);` at the end of the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the result_url after the loop, but the $.post upload request may not have been complete yet. What I would recommend is to put the code that uses result_url inside a continuation call back and call it after you  know that the last post request has completed.

e.g.

```
function continuation_code(result_url) {
    // all your code that uses result_url goes here.
}

var result_url = 'http://localhost/view/';
var num_results_returned = 0;
for(i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // Add URL to queue
    $('#url_queue').append('<div class="uploadifyQueueItem"><div class="cancel"><img src="/assets/img/cancel.png" /></div><span class="fileName">' + image_name_from_url(urls[i]) + '</span><div class="uploadifyProgress"><div class="uploadifyProgressBar"></div></div></div>');

    // Make a request to the upload script
    $.post('/upload', { url: urls[i], username: username }, function(response) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
            return;
        }
        if(response.img_code) {
            result_url += response.img_code + '&';
        }
        num_results_returned += 1;
        if (num_results_returned == urls.length) {
             continuation_code(result_url);
        }
    });
}
```