# Better way to pass variable from child to parent function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example

```
function getResult(field) {
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false, async: false});
    $.get("api.php?field="+field, function(i) {
        result = i;
    });
    return result;
};
```

The problem with this is that result becomes global.  If I do `var result = i;` then the parent function (getResult) cannot see the variable `result`.

Is there a clever way to do this?

The code that I have posted works correctly. I have set my AJAX calls to be done synchronously.

Comment: Please look on stackoverflow for this answer. It's asked at least once a day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX- response data not saved to global scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684014/ajax-response-data-not-saved-to-global-scope)

Comment: Just declare var result = ""; the first thing you do within getResult.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson That would return `undefined` since the Ajax-request is asynchronous...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Very true, wasn't thinking clearly, sry about that.

Comment: It's nothing to do with AJAX, it would be the same if I was using `$.each` I have my AJAX set to `async: false` anyway.  Please read the question in full before hand.

Comment: Returning in `$.each` would not work, but that's a slightly different thing. `$.each` is not asynchronous; you could define a variable outside `$.each` and return it afterwards. That does **not** work with AJAX, unless you set it to `async: false` indeed.

Comment: @jdborg but in that case, I guess the solution in my previous comment would do it, right? If you declare the variable within getResult it won't become global, but you should still be able to access it from within your $.get(). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @jdborg `async:false` is the stupidest thing you could every do.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson My mistake, works fine.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function doIt(arr) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(arr, function (y_u_key_jQuery_y_u_no_fix_api, value) {
    result.push(value);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Generally what you want to do is create a local variable in the outer function that the inner function manipulates through closure scope

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your AJAX call is synchronous. You can try this:

```
function getResult(field) {
  var result;
  $.get("api.php?field="+field, function(i) {
    result = i;
  });

  return result;
 };
```

This way, the variable `result` is no more global.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get()` is an asynchronous call. Trying to return something from it will not work like you think it will. If you want to do something with the result, you should do it in the success callback.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is the documentation on get.

Comment: It's nothing to do with AJAX, it would be the same if I was using $.each I have my AJAX set to async: false anyway. Please read the question in full before hand.

Comment: There was no possible way to know that you had async set to false. It wasn't shown that way and you didn't tell us. Based on the question as you originally posted it, my answer is correct.

Comment: If you read the descrption, I would have said it was an AJAX problem, I explained it was a problem with getting the variable passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually return a value from a asynchronous call, rather you have to depend upon the response will be be handled by a callback function to be called on response arrival.

```
function getResult(field, callback) {
    $.get("api.php?field=" + field, callback);
};
```

**USAGE**

```
getResult("someFieldName", function(data) {
    var result = data;
    // do something with the response from server
});
```