# How to return value after asynchronous ajax call is completed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, vimeo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX- response data not saved to global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684014/ajax-response-data-not-saved-to-global-scope)

Inside of function that gets the thumbnails of vimeo video using [vimeo API](http://vimeo.com/api):

```
    function getVimeoThumb(){
       var t = new Array();    
       $.ajax({
                'url' : 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id + '.json?callback=?',
                'dataType' : 'json',
                'async' : false,
                'type' : 'get',
                'success' : function(data) {

                t['img'] = data[0].thumbnail_large;
                t['src'] = 'vimeo';
                t['id'] = id;
            },
            'error' : function(){

                t['src'] = 'vimeo';
                t['img'] = '';
                t['id'] = id;
            }
        });
       return t;
     }
```

Even if I set "async" value to false, it is still not synchronous and hence variable "t" is undefined. Refer to jquery.com:

> "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation."

Any other solutions?

**UPDATE**: 
I need it to *return* the variable and not to call some other function. Because another function which calls it waits for it to return the values. This is kind of function, which is used throughout the site.

**SOLUTION: (for a future visitors)**
Since you can't do async call to different domain, I've create a server side code (on the same domain) to do the api call to vimeo. The process is as follows:
ajax call to local server side script -> api call to vimeo api -> get whatever is returned -> return it to ajax call
With this, you can have async calls. Hope this helps. Good luck and thanks to everyone, who tried to answer this question!

Answer (score 2):

JSONP isn't synchronous because it basically amounts to this...

`<script src="http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/12345.json?callback=cb12345"></script>`

Where the content of that script is...

`cb12345({ /* ... json data ... */ });`

So you basically have 2 choices:

- Embrace asynchronous code
- Try to convert the async code to synchronous

**Embracing Async**

Say this $.ajax code is in a function (which on a side note $.ajax is really pointless, using $.getScript is the same dang thing without jQuery trying to act like more is going on).

```
function GetVideoThumb(id, callback) {
    $.getScript('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id + '.json', function(data){
        callback({ img: data[0].thumbnail_large, src: 'vimeo', id: id });
    });
}
```

It means that whenever you call the `GetVideoThumb` function, you need to specify a callback that will handle whenever that works.

So say you had code that looked like this...

```
$('#myelem').click(function() {
    var thumb = GetVideoThumb(1234);
    $(this).attr('src', thumb.img);
});
```

You would change it to be more like this...

```
$('#myelem').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    GetVideoThumb(1234, function(thumb) {
        $(that).attr('src', thumb.img);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but my code is much more complicated than $(that).attr();... I'm trying to make it somewhat generic function, which is used throughout the site for different purposes.

Comment: Yeah, of course your code is more complicated than that.  The thing is, here's your situation.  Whenever this code hits the Vimeo server you're not quite sure how long it's going to take, right?  What you want to do is setup your code so that it's like this:  1.) ask Vimeo for this information, 2.) when Vimeo responds, then do this other complicated stuff using that data.  You can either trying to setup some kind of clever timer that guesses or you can just use a callback for when Vimeo does respond (what I've demonstrated above).

Comment: and yes that's my problem.. trying to setup my code. Here's one sample process: Get values from the form -> figure out what link it is (youtube, vimeo, etc.) -> get thumbnail for the video -> once it is received, update the website (without reloading) -> save it to DB -> close the pop up. Possibility that there might be other kind of videos shared (eg. youtube) adds complication, and if for some reason api doesn't fire up the callback, it won't be even saved in DB. I was playing around with the timer, but it's sooo unreliable.

Comment: long story short, it will be hard to change the code to fit the concept you have mentioned. Now I'm thinking to include a server side api to get those values from the vimeo api... I think it might work since it's not going to be async.